# CodeIgniter: changing password in controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to allow users to change their passwords in my site.
I'm getting stuck in the controller. My doubt is whether `$sql = $this->db->select("*")->from("logins_table")->where('lt_username',$this->session->userdata('email'))->get();` is working or not.

My controller:

```php
<?php

class Changepw extends MY_Controller {

    public function Changepwd(){
    }

    public function reset() // we will load models here to check with database
    {
        $sql = $this->db->select("*")->from("logins_table")->where('lt_username',$this->session->userdata('email'))->get();

        foreach ($sql->result() as $my_info) {
            $db_password = $my_info->lt_password;
            $db_id = $my_info->lt_id;
        }

        if($this->input->post('opassword') == $db_password  && ($this->input->post('npassword') != '') && ($this->input->post('cpassword')!='')) { 
                $fixed_pw = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($this->input->post('npassword')));
                $update = $this->db->query("Update 'logins_table' SET 'lt_password'= '$fixed_pw'  WHERE 'id'= '$db_id'")or die(mysql_error());
                //$this->form_validation->set_message('change',"sucess");
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>true));

        }else {
            //$this->form_validation->set_message('change', "err");

            echo json_encode(array("success"=>false));

        }
        exit;
    } 
}
```

and my view page is:

```
        <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="35%" class="heading">Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading">Existing Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="opassword" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr title="Ignore new password if you dont want to change password">
                <td   class="heading">New Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="npassword"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  class="heading">Confirm Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="cpassword"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button name="Submit" id="forgotBtn" class="customBtn" value="Submit">Save changes</button>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td ><div class="errorMsg" id="errMsg" style="display:none"> Error in updating </div></td>
            </tr>
            </tr> 
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </form>



$("#forgotBtn").on('click', function()
{

    $.post( "/changepw/reset",  $("#forgotForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        function(data) {
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.error == false) {
                $("#successMsg").hide();
            }else{
                $("#errMsg").show();
            }
        } );
    return false;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you be more specific on the issue you are facing?  You doubt if a piece of code works or not.  have you tried it?  what error do you get?

Comment: Agree with above comment. Do you KNOW it doesn't work? If you just suspect then run it. If you get an error please share it!

Comment: while we submit newpassword details showing "Error in updating" , further would like to check the error details but unable to find out the way how to check and resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I think according to the code, your error is here.

```
$this->input->post('opassword') == $db_password// this line
```

While storing password in database you have used `md5()`, but here you are just checking for the plain text which is wrong

```
md5($this->input->post('opassword')) == $db_password
```

This should help you.

Comment: thanks for the revert , i have cross check with above one ,still the issue not resolved

Comment: While we submit new password details showing "Error in updating" ,

Comment: can any one help, still issue persisting